# Setting Up Magento ver. 1.7 For Two Domains

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento

I am setting up Magento for two separate domains. I want to install two separate versions of Wordpress on each site, so I followed Magento's advice for a "Multiple Website Setup with Different Document Roots": http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/multi-store_set_up/multiple_website_setup_with_different_document_roots

1. I have installed Magento at /public_html and that version is working for the first site.
2. I have created another folder called public_html/bluewidgets.com.br/ and I have pointed bluewidgets.com.br at that domain.
3. I have a version of the .htaccess file and the index.php file at public_html/bluewidgets.com.br

index.php file changes:

```
$compilerConfig = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/includes/config.php';
$mageFilename = '/home/bluewidgets/public_html/app/Mage.php';
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] :      'bluewidgets_com_br';
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'website';
```

.htaccess changes:

```
RewriteBase /bluewidgets\.com\.br/
```

At this point I feel I am possibly making a mistake with the .htaccess file. When I comment out the line below, all of the pages load but the theme and images don't work. When I run the code below, the homepage loads but nothing else.

```
RewriteBase /bluewidgets\.com\.br/
```

I am also wondering if I possibly need to make a change to the configuration of the theme. So far I haven't.

Please could you suggest what I could try?

Comment: Since the bluewidget folder is the root for that domain, you would need to use `RewriteBase /`. (also no need to escape the dots with rewritebase)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I now have it working.  But I also had to change the base skin url, media URL and base javascript url to match the first domain (http://bluewidgets.com/skin/).

So at the moment images on bluewidgets.com.br are on the bluewidgets.com domain. Is there any way to solve this? Do I need to copy the files on bluewidgets.com and place them in the bluewidgets.com.br folder in my hosting account?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know magento :-(

Answer (score 0):

to set up two domains with two hosts you would use Manage Stores in Backend Configuration, you create additional store and assign a new store code to it (lets assume it's bluewidgets_br) then, in your vhost config for bluewidgets.br domain use:
SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE bluewidgets_br

also, in Configuration of br store go to system ->configuration -> design, switch to br store view, and update store details to point to different style folders (assuming you have different design/(...) folders prepared for both stores)